# Replace word from multiple .txt files in nodejs

Tags: node.js

In a directory there are multiple files with different extensions. I have to find and select .txt files and  from these all .txt files  there are some words I have to replace with new words.

say , 4 files from my directory are :

```
File1.txt
File2.txt
File3.txt
File4.txt
```

now I have to `replace word 'mobile' to 'laptop' from all .txt files`

than again I have to `replace word 'School' to 'College' from all txt.files`

and again `replace word 'banana' to 'Mango' from all txt.files`

and `then save the file.`

```
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')

const dirpath = path.join(__dirname, '/')

fs.readdir(dirpath, function(err, files) {
  const Files = files.filter(el => path.extname(el) === '.txt')

for (let i=0; i < Files.length; i++) {
      console.log(Files[i])


      var fs = require('fs')
      fs.readFile(Files[i], 'utf8', function (err,data) {
        if (err) {
          return console.log(err);
        }

                var result = data.replace(/mobile/g, 'laptop');
                fs.writeFile(Files[i], result, 'utf8', function (err) {
                  if (err) return console.log(err);
                });

                var result2 = data.replace(/School/g, 'College');
                fs.writeFile(Files[i], result2, 'utf8', function (err) {
                  if (err) return console.log(err);
              });
     
      });

    }
```

When I run this program only 2nd replace part is working,what should I do!

Comment: `replace` returns a new string and doesn't modify the original string. And you are both times calling `replace` on the original `data`. You should call `result2 = result.replace(...)` Furthermore I'd suggest to ditch that first `writeFile` because 1) it's async and will mess up things if you don't wait for it properly and 2) it's unnecessary because you are writing to the same file twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing

```
var result = data.replace(/mobile/g, 'laptop');
fs.writeFile(Files[i], result, 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
});

var result2 = data.replace(/School/g, 'College');
fs.writeFile(Files[i], result2, 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
});
```

you're

- first, saving the first replaced text to the file
- then, replacing the *original* text with the second string, and saving that to the file

Not sure what you were trying to achieve with that first write - if you really wanted two `writeFile`s, you'd need to wait for the first to finish, and then call `readFile` again to get the new content, and then call `.replace` on that content. But why not just ditch that first `writeFile` entirely and use the string you already have a reference to? (Don't replace `data`, the original string, but `result`, the result of the first replacement - or, don't create an intermediate variable at all)

```
fs.readFile(Files[i], 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    const result = data
        .replace(/mobile/g, 'laptop')
        .replace(/School/g, 'College');
    fs.writeFile(Files[i], result, 'utf8', function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
    });
});
```

If you wanted to have an indicator when all files have been replaced, use the `fs.promises` API and `Promise.all` instead of the callback-based API.